# Is there an easy way to have the file names and their last modified dates listed?

Tags: python-3.x, time, operating-system

I´m actually trying to list (filename and their last modified date) within a directory: But when I run my command, I´m actually having just the list of the files but with the modified dates all similar. Can someone help identify the problem in my script?

Comment: Add your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to attach your script, but these few lines do the job (python 3):

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

search_dir = "/example/path"
os.chdir(search_dir)
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(search_dir)) #filter just files, no directories
paths = [os.path.join(search_dir, f) for f in files] # path for each file
fileNames = [os.path.basename(x) for x in paths] # list of file names
dates = [os.path.getmtime(x) for x in paths] # list of modification dates

filesDates = list(zip(fileNames, dates)) # zip names and dates
filesDates.sort(key = lambda x: x[1]) # sort by dates

for x in filesDates: # print, converting timestamp to human readable format
    print(x[0], ' modified: ', datetime.fromtimestamp(x[1], tz=None))
```

example output:

```
talsh_En_T2.F90  modified:  2023-01-19 11:31:59.768919
tenpi.py  modified:  2023-01-26 16:33:28.003705
test.py  modified:  2023-02-02 11:56:24.067713
```

Comment: Many thanks Janbrandejs. Very useful. All working fine.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your support, I will trying it and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: Hi Janbrandejs! Just a quick one. How does the code will look like if we are to consider the folder within the main folder, since this codes only consider the files within a folder and not in the folder at the second layer.

Comment: please see (and like :) ) the second answer @NdofiVontade

Answer (score 0):

improved answer, with the possibility of including first level subdirectories

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

dir0 = "/example/path"

all = [os.path.join(dir0, f) for f in os.listdir(dir0)] #abs path of each file in search_dir

for subdir in filter(os.path.isdir, all):
    all.extend([os.path.join(subdir, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir)]) # everything in subdir

paths = list(filter(os.path.isfile, all)) #keep only files

paths.sort(key = lambda f: os.path.getmtime(f)) # sort by dates

for f in paths: # print, converting timestamp to human readable format
    relPath = os.path.relpath(f, dir0)
    modified = os.path.getmtime(f)
    print(relPath, ' modified: ', datetime.fromtimestamp(modified, tz=None))
```